# Coroutine delays not operating during subsequent recomposition

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, kotlin-coroutines

In a Kotlin Composable, coroutines with different delays are used in a loop to animate the display of cards sequentially. This works when the screen is shown initially, but when the cards are changed (on a button click), the animation ignores the delays and displays all the cards at once.

Here is a simplified version of the code.

```
       ConstraintLayout(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
       ) {
        val cardWidthAndHeight = ComposeResizeHelper.getCardSize( ... )
        val buttonRefList: MutableList<ConstrainedLayoutReference> = ArrayList()
        val horizontalGuidelineList = getHorizontalGuidelineList( ... )
        val verticalGuidelineList = getVerticalGuidelineList( ... )
        val animationDelay = (300 * (5.5 / animationSpeed)).toLong()

        for (i in 1..n) { // where n is the number of cards
        var movedCard by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false                            )
        }
        val interactionSource = remember {
            MutableInteractionSource()
        }
        val coroutine = rememberCoroutineScope()
        val animationDuration = (500 * (5.5 / animationSpeed)).toInt()

        val sizeTarget =
            if (animateStateInt == 1) {
            DpSize.Zero
            } else {
            if (movedCard) {
                cardWidthAndHeight
            } else {
                DpSize.Zero
            }
            }
        val animatedWidth = animateDpAsState(
            targetValue = sizeTarget.width, label = "width$i",
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = animationDuration)
            )
        val animatedHeight = animateDpAsState(
            targetValue = sizeTarget.height, label = "height$i",
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = animationDuration)
        )
        buttonRefList.add(createRef())
        val j = i - 1
        Button( // this button does nothing at the moment - it is really a 'card'
            onClick = {},
            enabled = false,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            modifier = Modifier
            .size(
                width =
                    if (animateStateInt == 1) {
                    0f.dp
                    } else {
                    animatedWidth.value
                    },
                height =
                    if (animateStateInt == 1) {
                    0f.dp
                    } else {
                    animatedHeight.value
                    }
            )
            .constrainAs(buttonRefList[j]) {
                start.linkTo(verticalGuidelineList[j])
                bottom.linkTo(horizontalGuidelineList[j])
            }
        ) {
            Box( ... ) { ... }
        }

        if (!movedCard) {
            coroutine.launch {
            val press = PressInteraction.Press(Offset.Zero)
            interactionSource.emit(press)
            delay(i.toLong() * animationDelay) // here is where the delays are set
            movedCard = true
            interactionSource.emit(PressInteraction.Release(press))
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

What can be done to have the delays operate every time?